# How to update my dictionary to hold both Start and Endpoints

Tags: python, dictionary

A point is defined as the coordinates of a non-digit: in state.

I have a StartPoint A = (x,y) and I also have an EndPoint a = (x,y).

**ExampleState**: 'a' == state[0][0] and 'A' == state[4][5]

Now what I would like is a dictionary in form of:

```
d = {'a' : 
            { 'E' : (x,y) } # EndPoint
            { 'S' : (x,y) } # StartPoint
    }
```

This is what I have so far, and I feel silly for asking but I don't know how to proceed from here

```
state = ["a224C22300000", 
         "0001643722B00", 
         "0b27275100000", 
         "00c7256500000", 
         "0006A45000000"]

# Find start and endpoints for the flow
# A point is the coordinates in state where it is not a digit
points = {}
for i in range(len(state)):
    for x in range(len(state[i])):
        if(not state[i][x].isdigit()):
            if(state[i][x].lower() != state[i][x]):
                points.update({state[i][x]:(i,x)})
            else:
                points.update({state[i][x]:(i,x)})

# After completion points = {'a': (0, 0), 'b': (2, 1), 'c': (3, 2), 'B': (1, 10), 'A': (4, 4), 'C': (0, 4)}
```

I also feel like I could find the start and endpoints using a regex much faster, but that is not my question.

Comment: It's not really clear to me how the input (`state`?) maps to these start points and end points.

Comment: Furthermore your expected output is not a valid dictionary.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know it is not correct, but was unsure what the correct format was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your expected output is *not* a valid dictionary. I assume however you want to generate:

```
d = {'a' : 
        { 'E' : (x,y) , # EndPoint
          'S' : (x,y) } # StartPoint
}
```

In that case you can simply write:

```
from collections import defaultdict

points = defaultdict(dict)
for i,stati in enumerate(state):
    for j,statij in enumerate(stati):
        if statij.isalpha():
            low_statij = statij.lower()
            if statij.isupper():
                points[low_statij]['S'] = (i,j)
            else:
                points[low_statij]['E'] = (i,j)
```

This generates:

```
>>> points
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'b': {'E': (2, 1), 'S': (1, 10)}, 'a': {'E': (0, 0), 'S': (4, 4)}, 'c': {'E': (3, 2), 'S': (0, 4)}})
```

In case you want to convert it back to a vanilla dictionary, you can call `dict` on `points`:

```
>>> dict(points)
{'b': {'E': (2, 1), 'S': (1, 10)}, 'a': {'E': (0, 0), 'S': (4, 4)}, 'c': {'E': (3, 2), 'S': (0, 4)}}
```

Comment: With the defaultdict I can call startPointB = points['b']['S'] right? Because that is what I would like to achieve

Comment: @Ludisposed: yes. But as stated at the bottom of the answer. You can easily convert it to a vanilla dictionary (where you can call `points['b']['S']` as well).

Comment: Dankjewel! This will help me achieve what I need.